# Stream csv file download immediately without waiting

Tags: java, streaming, outputstream

I have REST API, which calls a method to retrieve CSV, as csv can be millions of rows, I am retrieving 50k rows at a time, I want the download to begin as soon as I receive first query result and subsequently keep writing to the same file.

I have written the following code, but still the file download starts only after all the result is retrieved.

```
@GET
    @Path("network/all/stats/csv/download")
    @Produces({"text/csv"})
    public Response downloadCSV(UIAffiliateRequest uiInstallsRequest) {StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                    int off=0;
                    try {
                        CSVResponseType rs;

                        do {
                            rs = installsDao.getCSVResult(uiInstallsRequest, off);
                            String lines[] = rs.getFileName().split("\\r?\\n");
                            for (String path : lines) {
                                writer.write(path.toString() + "\n");
                            }
                            writer.flush();
                            off+=50000;
                        }
                        while (rs.isEmpty());
                    }
                    catch (DaoException e) {
                        ResponseUtils.getDataAccessErrorResponse(e);
                    }
                }
            };

            return Response.ok(stream).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=resp.csv").build();

    }
```

Comment: I think your problem might be in the installsDao.getCSVResult() call, this one seems to be blocking. I am comparing to the code of this article 
https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response
if you notice the paths variable is fully processed outside of the StreamingOutput implementation. You need to figure out a better algorithm for the pagination of the CSV results, maybe move the query out and return a stream from it instead of pagination but then again I am not sure if this would help.